# Convert Polygon to Point thru multiple shapefiles

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, convert

I am trying to convert several polygon shapefiles into point shapefiles. I can get it to do it one at a time but when I try to get it to go all of them it will just list the files and then give me an error.

One file at a time:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
import glob

env.workspace = "F:/Thesis/Aridisol/"

inFeatures="F:/Thesis/Aridisol/1_Percent_Random/Polygon/Band4A_900_1.shp"
#  Set local variables

outFeatureClass = "F:/Thesis/Aridisol/1_Percent_Random/Point/Band4A_900_1.shp"

# Use FeatureToPoint function to find a point inside 
arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management(inFeatures, outFeatureClass, "INSIDE")

print "Processing Complete"
```

Multiple files:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os
import glob

env.workspace = "F:/Thesis/Aridisol/"
outWorkspace= "F:/Thesis/Aridisol/3_Percent_Random/Point/"

featureclasses=glob.glob("F:/Thesis/Aridisol/3_Percent_Random/Polygon/*.shp")

# Get a list of ascii
for fc in featureclasses:
    #Print list
    print fc
    outFeatureClass=fc 

# Use FeatureToPoint function to find a point inside
arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management(featureclasses, outFeatureClass, "INSIDE")

print "Processing Complete"
```

Comment: Your feature to point isn't inside your loop, you still need to do them still one at a time instead of trying to supply a list of strings. If you want the output merged then use merge or append. Instead of using glob use arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*.shp') http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000023000000 ... what error do you get? I bet it's something to do with the feature class already existing as out is the same as in, you really should do something about giving the output a different name or path, perhaps outFeatureClass=os.path.join(outWorkspace,fc).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. All questions should always contain the **exact** version of software in use, and should always include the **exact** error, not just "then give me an error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include your `arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management()` inside your loop, otherwise it will only run on the last shapefile.  Personally I'd also use `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` instead of `glob`, filtering on `Polygon` to limit your search to polygon shapefiles.

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "F:/Thesis/Aridisol/3_Percent_Random/Polygon"
outWorkspace = "F:/Thesis/Aridisol/3_Percent_Random/Point/"

featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.SHP", "Polygon") 

# Loop through polygon shapefiles
for fc in featureclasses:
    print fc
    # Give new shapefile name by appending '_point'
    newfc = "{}_point.shp".format(os.path.splitext(fc)[0])
    # Output filepath
    outFeatureClass = os.path.join(outWorkspace, newfc)

    # Use FeatureToPoint function to find a point inside 
    # and save to output filepath
    arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management(fc, outFeatureClass, "INSIDE")

print "Processing Complete"
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! This was much easier than I was making it out to be.